# Managing Active Forms when Closing a Form C#

Tags: c#, forms, focus, formclosing

I have an issue with an app when the user updates a record on form 2, and form 2 closes as it should do, instead of the focus being back on the previous form 1 (i.e. records viewer), the whole app loses focus (for example focus reverts back to Excel Spreadsheet and not the record viewer).

Anyone else experienced similar issues?

I am using `this.close()` to close my form 2.

Comment: i tried to reproduce the problem but i didn't get the same problem. Can you show us some code and maybe try to call the second form with ```form2.ShowDialog();```

Comment: Hi I have tried different scenarios, it appears to happens when the user clicks on the excel sheet, and then they click on form 2 to update the record and the focus reverts back to the excel sheet once Form 2 closes. They are using a Dual Monitor setup. I think I need to write code to make Form 2 to re-focus on Record Viewer (form 1) once form 2 is closed.   For Form 1 I am using `AddReserve Window = new AddReserve();
           Window.Show();`

Comment: Just tested with `ShowDialog()` and it works! I will look into how to manage between instantiated Forms in future, but for now this works perfectly. The only drawback is the user cannot open multiple records, but for now this will be fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. im not so fit with winforms but im happy that i could help you